# How to get data from json to view in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

I have an Angular controller that gets data via a service from 2 different json files, and I need to pass that data to a view.

The controller file:

```
.controller('MainController', ['info', function (info){
    var vm = this;

    info.getAddresses().then(function(data) {
      vm.addresses = data.addresses;
    });

    info.getNames().then(function(data) {
      vm.names = data.names;
    });
    console.log(this);
}])
```

The getAddresses and getNames functions are just $.get('json-url').

If I use console.log(this) in the controller just before the closing bracket, I can see in the console the data below:

[image: console log]
but I cannot access that 2 properties from the view. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you add some code?

Comment: Post the code of your controller please

Comment: I updated the description with the controller's code

Comment: could you share your code in the view as well? something like `<span>{{vm.addresses}}</span>`

Comment: I the view I tried with {{vm}}, {{vm.addresses}}, an ng-repeat through {{vm.addresses}}, but nothing display any information

Comment: does `{{vm}}` gives anything other than an empty string? If not, there must be something wrong elsewhere.. for example a typo... your complete code will be helpful in this case..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably a digest cycle issue. Adding `$scope.$apply` would fix the issue. 
`$.get()` from jQuery alter the value of `vm.names` but it's not part of the Angular digest cycle.

Here is a working example, hope this helps

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .factory('info', function() {
    var mock = function() {
      return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        resolve({
          "names": ['Alice', 'Bob']
        });
      });
    };

    return {
      getNames: mock
    };
  })
  .controller('MainController', function(info,$scope) {
    var vm = this;
    info.getNames().then(function(data) {
      vm.names = data.names;
      // trigger $apply manually
      $scope.$apply();
    });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController as vm">
    {{vm.names}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the $apply() method worked. I used it in the original controller, applying it after passing the data to the $scope.

Answer (score 0):

use scope variable to store the data instead of var

```
.controller('MainController', ['info', '$scope', $scope, function (info){
$scope.vm = this;

info.getAddresses().then(function(data) {
  $scope.vm.addresses = data.addresses;
});

info.getNames().then(function(data) {
  $scope.vm.names = data.names;
});
console.log(this);
```

}])

and call this scope variable in your view like

```
<tr ng-repeat = item in vm>
   <td>you can get your data here</td>
</tr>
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning your data to a *variable* and not to the `$scope`.

Your *controller* should be like this

```
.controller('MainController', ['info', '$scope', function (info, $scope){    

    info.getAddresses().then(function(data) {
      $scope.addresses = data.addresses;
    });

    info.getNames().then(function(data) {
      $scope.names = data.names;
    });

    console.log($scope);

}])
```

Comment: using of $scope is not necessary as OP is using the controller as syntax

Comment: Well, hes trying to pass the data to the view which is impossible when storing the data as properties on the callback function. `OP is using the controller as syntax` he never mentions this.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have used `controller as` syntax. So you need to use it into `ng-controller`. Check below code.

```
    <div ng-controller="MainController as vm">
       <div ng-repeat="vm.addresses in address">{{ address }}</div>
       <div ng-repeat="vm.names in name">{{ name}}</div>
</div>
```

If address or name is json object then you need to use specific key within address or name object.

Answer (score -2):

**For Angular 2+**
Hold the json response in some variable:

```
public data:any=your json response;
```

And then in view, display it vi using *ngFor directive:

```
<p *ngFor="let d of data">{{d}}</p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need a solution for Angular 1.*

Comment: Ok, For what i remember you can use $scope to hold json response and in view use ng-repeat to iterate and display.
<p ng-repeat="d in data">{{d}}</p>